# Are there specific limits to the power of the Warp?

Tags: rogue-trader

I'm playing in a Rogue Trader campaign with someone who thinks the Warp can fix everything. They believe just because they are a Navigator and in touch with the Emperor and the Astronomicon, if they go to a hive planet they can make every worker in the Administratum do whatever they want just by positive thought. They think they can make a dragon non-hostile just by projecting their love for it through the Warp.

How can I communicate to the player that's not how the Warp works? Are there any rules to stop them ruining everyone else's game?

Comment: @SPavel That might take some more explanation in the form of an answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that comments aren't for chatting! Thanks. :) If there are details that are unclear in the question then the comments can be used by others to ask for clarifications; if there are details that need to be added to the question they can be added using the [edit] feature. (For more info see [What are comments?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment))

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If I'd have posted this question with my other account it would have got downvoted.

Comment: If the first comment is confusing, allow me to give some context: SPavel added a comment that looked like a one-line answer; it was deleted because comments aren't for answering (that's what answers below here are for). I added a comment asking SPavel to write that as an answer, if it's really an answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am confused by the above answer and I'm not sure if it was good or bad.

Comment: I'm closing this question because the user is socking around a ban.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have not been banned.

Comment: Yes Peter David Carter-Poulsen, you really really have.